# Compactness hypothesis in Heine's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Here is the proof from Apostol's analysis
[image]

I think the main point in the proof is the existence of a smallest radius among $\frac{r_1}{2}\ ,\ \frac{r_2}{2}......,\frac{r_k}{2}$, but I don't see how the compactness hypothesis is necessary for this. Suppose $A$ wasn't compact, then the set of radii in question may be infinite. However, this is a set of real numbers which are bounded below by zero and hence have an infimum which can be used in the rest of the argument and it will still be valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infimum of an infinite sequence of positive numbers can be $0$ as in the case of $(\frac 1 n)$. You cannot have $\delta =0$ in the proof.

Comment: Can't we choose the radii such that none of them is zero?

Comment: $\frac 1 n$ is not $0$ for any $n$ but there is no $\delta >0$ such that $\delta \leq \frac 1 n$ for all $n$.

Comment: here is how I understand this. for every point $a$ in $A$ there is a radius $r$ such that whenever the distance between $a$ and $p$ is less than $r$ the distance between $f(a)$ and $f(p)$ is less than epsilon over $2$. These radii form an infinite sequence of real numbers. If this sequence contains a smallest nonzero element then the rest of the argument can be carried out. So suppose the set $A$ isn't compact but the infinite sequence in question has such an element, is this the theorem true then?

Comment: @Km356 A converse of this is available here: go to statmathbc.wordpress.com , open the catalog and click on Problems 201-300. Problem 215 there has the proof.

Comment: I downloaded the file but the statement is there without proof.

Comment: @Km356 I am sorry about that. But if you send me an email I will send you my entire collection of problems with solutions. My email address can be found in the catalog.